# Home page is not accessible after clicking to Blog page [theme-twenty-seventeen]

Tags: theme-twenty-seventeen

vanafnu.eu is my website. Once I've clicked on Blog in the header, I go to the Blog page and I cannot return to the Home page anymore via the menu bar. Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the link in the Menu option. This solved it.